# How to setup more granular font change when using Cmd/Ctrl + scroll wheel in IntelliJ products?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, fonts, webstorm, font-size

Right now the jumps between fonts are huge. It is either too small or too big.

In Qt based apps e.g. in Kate you can change font size with your mouse wheel very precisely in small steps, it almost looks to be fluid/continuous.

However in WebStorm or other IntelliJ software it jumps in big steps.

Any idea how to step using 12, 13, 14, 15 px fonts instead of 12, 16, 20 etc. ?

Here is a video to show what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/Yv7mXcq.mp4

As you can see in the video, Kate (on the right) has a much smoother font changes in smaller pixel jumps than WebStorm (on the left).

Comment: What OS do you use? For me, on MacOS steps are 11, 12, 13, 14.

Comment: Monterey 12.3.1 . It is the same no matter if it's Webstorm, Idea, or Goland etc. Can you upload your font changes video?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be related to my mouse, because on the touch pad I can cmd + two fingers scroll it much smoother. Any idea how to set up a keyboard short cut to increase/decrease the font size without visiting the settings menu all the time I want to change it?

Comment: 1. Press Shift + Shift to open "Commands" Window
2. Type "Increase font size" to find the command
3. Press Alt + Enter to assign a shorcut
4. Repeat the same steps to "Decrease font size" command.

Comment: Can you repeat the "shift" shortcut? Shift + Shift?

Comment: Yes, double Shift.